# Nano Color Syntax for Python3

Tags: python-3

Currently if I use nano to edit a file with a `.py` extension nano will recognize it as a Python file and will color the syntax, but for Python 2. Is there anyway for nano to color syntax to Python3 instead as that's what I know how to use?

Comment: How do you expect the color to be different? All nano does is go by the file ending and apply the rules it has for that file ending.

Comment: I suppose if you know what you are doing you could edit `/usr/share/nano/python.nanorc`

Comment: I wrote this for the blog which should get you sorted out https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146308635329/improving-the-usability-of-the-nano-editor